# How do I display the variant image when the color swatch of a variant is hovered on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

On a product card in the collections page and featured products section, I have product cards of each product with an image and below the image, I have color swatches of the variants the products have.

When the image is hovered on, it shows the 2nd product image: `{{ product.images[1] | img_url: '300x400', scale: 3, crop: 'center' }}` refers to the 2nd image from the product images array.

However, when a color swatch is hovered on, I want the featured image to change to the variant image on mouseover.

The code for the product card image:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  <!-- this div contains both product-card snippet and color variant snippet -->
  <div class="product-card w-50 mb3" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">

    <!-- product card snippet code  -->
    <a class="link-to-product" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
      {% if product.featured_image %}
        <div class="card-image reveal mb3">
          <img src="{{ product | img_url: '300x400', scale: 3, crop: 'center' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
          <img class="hidden" src="{{ product.images[1] | img_url: '300x400', scale: 3, crop: 'center' }}" />
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <div class="card-info flex flex-column items-center tc">
        <h5 class="mb2 f6 f5-ns">{{ product.title }}</h5>
        <p class="price mb3">
          {% if product.compare_at_price %}
            <span class="strike">{{ product.compare_at_price | money_with_currency }}</span>
          {% endif %}
          {{ product.price | money_with_currency }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!-- end of color product card snippet -->

    <!-- color variant hover snippet code  -->
    <div class="option-colors">
      <div class="product-option-row flex justify-center flex-column flex-row-ns tc tl-ns mb4">
        <div class="option-values">
          {% for value in option.values %}
            {% assign radio_id = 'option-' | append: option_name | append: '-' | append: value | handleize %}

            {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
              {%- if variant.title contains value -%}
                {%- assign productColorOptionURL = product.url | append: "?variant=" | append: variant.id -%}
                {%- assign variantImgSrc = variant.image.src | img_url: '300x400', scale: 3, crop: 'center' -%}
                {%- break -%}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}

            <a href="{{ productColorOptionURL }}" data-variant-img="{{ variantImageSrc }}">
              <label for="{{ radio_id }}" class="color-swatch-list">
                {% if force_colors == true %}
                  {% include 'option-color' with color: value %}
                {% else %}
                  {{ value }}
                {% endif %}
              </label>
            </a>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of color variant hover snippet -->

  </div>
  <!-- main div ends -->
```

The jQuery code

```
let
  productCardContainer = '[data-product-id]',
  productVariantSwatch = '[data-variant-img]',
  productMainImage = '.card-image img';

$(productCardContainer)
  .find(productVariantSwatch).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).(productMainImage).attr('src', $(this).data("variant-img"));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute with the value of the variant image URL to the color swatch link e.g.

```
<a href="{{ productColorOptionURL }}" data-variant-img="{{ variantImgSrc }}">
```

Then add `onmouseover` event handlers attached to these color swatch links which will get the variant image URL from the currently hovered element and set it as a value for the `src` attribute of the current featured image `<img>` element e.g.

Replace your jQuery code with this:

```
$("[data-variant-img]").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".product-card").find(".card-image img:first").attr('src', $(this).data("variant-img"));
});
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried and it doesn't work, I'm also not sure whether to add this in application.js or within {% javascript %} on the same liquid page

  var variantImg = $('[data-variant-img]');
  $('[data-variant-img]').mouseover(function() {
    document.querySelector('.card-image img').src = this.dataset.variantImg;"
  })

Comment: I would add it to .js file. The code from your previous comment contains an extra quote before the closing brace. Also, the featured image selector should be more concrete and contain product ID, otherwise all the `.card-image img` will be changed on the page. And finally, in the color swatch you use just `variant.image.src` but you would need to use `img_url` filter to get the image URL, so you would need to replace it to `{%- assign variantImgSrc = variant.image.src | img_url: '300x400', scale: 3, crop: 'center' -%}`, according to the code from the question.

Comment: One more thing actually, if you use jQuery, than the code can be replaced to `$('[data-variant-img]').mouseover(function() { $('.card-image img').attr('src', $(this).data("variant-img")); })`

Comment: thank you so much for helping out again! I just tried and updated my code here as well  but I'm struggling to specifically select the specific image as I'm new to jQuery and there isn't any change yet and I'm not sure what I did wrong

Comment: Sorry, there's a type, you need to replace `variantImageSrc` to `variantImgSrc`

Comment: and when I add that code, the hovering function doesn't work but the product page images slick breaks

Comment: @Varshini, see updated answer, replace your jQuery code with the code provided

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to target the main select for the product page and get the image from the variant.

```
<select class="main-select" name="id" style="display: none;">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <option 
      value="{{variant.id}}"
      data-image="{{variant.image | img_url: '1024x'}}"
    >{{ variant.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select><!-- /# -->
```

This will require JS logic in order to target the correct option from the select.

You should be able to reuse the logic for the change event and apply it on hover event with the exception of changing the main select value.